# android notification show Image from string without unicode

Tags: java, android

i want to show different image or smiley in notification from string 
for example

"Hi i am your friend  Sam"

i have tried using image setter 
and also string builder but it show obj obj instead of image
below  full code

```
String mystring = "Hi i am your friend <img /src='friend.png'/> Sam";
final NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.eat2, "notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
// This pending intent will open after notification click
PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Home.class), 0);
note.setLatestEventInfo(this,mystring, mystring, i);
// After uncomment this line you will see number of notification arrived note.number = 2;
mgr.notify(12, note);
```

Comment: Show what you had tried so far. *Show code* @Ankita

Comment: @SilentKiller but result doesn't come

Comment: hi i am your friend <img src='friend.png'> sam

Comment: you want to show HTML content in Notification ?

Comment: yes @SilentKiller you are right

Comment: its in drawable @SilentKiller

Comment: Show your full code please

Comment: ok wait @SilentKiller

Comment: You just want to show icon in notification or it must be inside that text ?

Comment: @AnkitaBansal,I think it is not possible with push notification text.

Comment: then any other way you know or can you give example of unicode

Comment: @AnkitaBansal,I'm not sure about it but let try to use Spannable String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think It's not possible to show image as HTML content inside notification. You can show image and text in notification as below.

your `Notification` Should be like as below if you want to show any Image/Icon to your Notification

```
Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message Received")
    .setContentText("Hi I am your friend Sam")
    // Here you can specify an image but it will display as icon on the left side of Notification.
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.friend)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setSound(soundUri)
    .build();
```

Comment: i agree with you but i want in string can you explain me how to use unicode plz

Comment: @AnkitaBansal what kind of image you want to show ? is it black and white or what ? show that friend image.

Comment: @silenKiller its like smiley

Comment: please add that smiley to your question.